# Dotnetnuke: retrieve CurrentPage altenateUrls to inset into hreflang header

Tags: c#, .net, url, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

With dnn multilanguage 9.1.1 I need to insert hreflang meta in the headers of all pages.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="http://www.acme.com/it/" title="Italian">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.acme.com/en/" title="English">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.acme.com/de/" title="German">
```

I found the way to get CurrentUrl using:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl
```

I've found that in SitemapBuilder.cs there some commented code that implement alternate hreflang:

```
private void AddURL(SitemapUrl sitemapUrl, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("url");
        writer.WriteElementString("loc", sitemapUrl.Url);
        writer.WriteElementString("lastmod", sitemapUrl.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        writer.WriteElementString("changefreq", sitemapUrl.ChangeFrequency.ToString().ToLower());
        writer.WriteElementString("priority", sitemapUrl.Priority.ToString("F01", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        //if (sitemapUrl.AlternateUrls != null)
        //{
        //    foreach (AlternateUrl alternate in sitemapUrl.AlternateUrls)
        //    {
        //        writer.WriteStartElement("link", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
        //        writer.WriteAttributeString("rel", "alternate");
        //        writer.WriteAttributeString("hreflang", alternate.Language);
        //        writer.WriteAttributeString("href", alternate.Url);
        //        writer.WriteEndElement();
        //    }
        //}
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

How can I get all alternate URL for current page?

Comment: What do you mean by alternate url? A different domain name mapped to the same portal? However you could mean http://www.acme.com/default.aspx?tabid=xx, that also works.

Comment: For alternate URL I mean all translated relative page of the current URL (like the commented snippet). In my case I've multilanguage website based on folder like: www.acme.com/en, www.acme.com/es etc.

Comment: I found also that using: DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CurrentPage.DefaultLanguageTab.LocalizedTabs I've all translated pages but no information about language full name. Is this the correct way?